# How to calcualte a downtime of all entities for a month with Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, promql

There is a metric which returns 1 if an entity is reachable and 0 if not. I want to calculate a downtime only if all entities are down. I know that is possible via the `sum()` function like `sum(a_metric_name{some_label="some_value"}) == 0`. But I don't get how to combine such expression with the `avg_over_time()` function to get a downtime in minutes for the last month like here

```
(1-avg_over_time(a_metric_name{some_label="some_value"}[30d])) * 30 * 24 * 60
```

Is it even possible with Prometheus only or I have to create a custom exporter?

I don't know where to start and will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To get percentage of time when all values of metric are equal to 0 you can use

```
1 - avg_over_time((sum(a_metric_name{some_label="some_value"}) == 0 or vector(1)) [30d:])
```

Here:

- `sum(a_metric_name{some_label="some_value"}) == 0` returns 0 if all metrics returned by `a_metric_name{some_label="some_value"}` are equal to 0. If it is not equal to 0 - doesn't return anything,
- `or vector(1)` returns 1 if previous expression didn't return value,
- `(...)[30d:]` uses a subquery to return range of results for previous expressions over last 30 days with default resolution (`evaluation_time` from configuration)
- `avg_over_time(...)` calculates average value over results in returned range, and subsequently percentage of the time at least one instance was not equal to 0.

Please also notice, that this query assumes you have no metric absence blocks, which is might very well not be the case for custom metric. But if you are using autometric `up`, this shouldn't be a problem.

Additionally this solution is tailored for aggregation over all the metrics supplied by selector. If later you'd like to introduce some aggregation (for purpose of the following example let's assume aggregation over label cluster), you'd need to change expression a bit: `vector(1)` couldn't be used as it doesn't allow dynamic labels. But wi can solve it with a bit of arithmetic:

```
1 - avg_over_time((sum(a_metric_name{some_label="some_value"}) == 0 or sum(a_metric_name{some_label="some_value"}) * 0 + 1) [30d:])
```

Comment: Thank you, @markalex. But what if I have some blank spaces? I mean absence of a metric. Is there any way to deal with that?

Comment: @KoyGwaewion, yes it's possible.  Use `vector(1) and a_metric_name{some_label="some_value"}) > 0 or vector(0)` inside sum instead of the current expression.